# 500 error (CSRF) when login button doubleclicked in Django

Tags: django, authentication, csrf, double-click

I have a django application with a custom user system (that inherits from the base user system). However, I've noticed that if you happen to click the login button twice, you will sometimes get a CSRF error (if running in debug) or 500 error on our site. If you press the back button, it will redirect you to the first page you should see when you login. However, is there a way to prevent this error on a doubleclick? It turns out that our users are prone to this behaviour.

Comment: would you be fine with a client side approach?

Answer (score 1):

disable the login button after (the first) click. Using JQuery you can

```
$('#id_form').one('submit', function() {
    $(this).find('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled','disabled');
});
```